# Text size not affected by font size change

Tags: android, font-size, text-size

I use `.setTextSize()` to change the size of text depending of screen resolution. Problem is when user changes font size in settings to `>normal` my UI looks bad.

1. the units used in this case are `sp`, but can it be changed with code to be `dp`? That wouldn't be affected by changing font size, right?
2. I know I can use `float f = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;` to get system font size and then use `if-else` to `.setTextSize()` based on screen resolution and font size, but I also found this piece of code

`Configuration mConfiguration = new Configuration(); 
mConfiguration.fontScale = 1;
getResources().getConfiguration().setTo(mConfiguration);`

which should make my app ignore system font size, but it doesn't work for me. Not only does it not work but it crashes my app every time I start `Alert Dialog`. So is there any way I could make my app ignore system font size?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way should be to use dp instead of sp, as you said.

The caveat to this is that if they change their screen zoom, that will change the scale of what a dp means, just as changing font size changes the scale of what an sp means.

Edit: I agree with [Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan) that you shouldn't ever do this. Instead, make your views adaptable to various sizes.

For example, instead of making a TextView 25dp in height, try making it wrap-content.

The exception to this would be if your company gave you the icons as a font file, and you already have large icons. Believe it or not, some designers deliver icons as .ttf files.

Answer (score -1):

You should NOT do that.  If the user changes the global size, its because they have a hard time seeing things.  They have a physical disability, and are trying to compensate it.  You should not try to override their choice.  Not only is it an jerkish thing to do, but it means they'll have a hard time using your app at all.  Its the equivalent of trying to stop a blind person from using text to speech on your app because you have really cool background music.  Or getting rid of a handicap ramp because you have nice stairs.

Either fix your layout so that it looks good at any size, or let the user decide if the app looks too bad and decrease his size.  Do not override it.

Comment: :) My app uses empty licence plate images, and adds plate number over it, and it spans over the entire width of the screen. The height of the text is like 20% of screen height. Text size is already pretty big, but one user reported to me that he is using full 1440x2880 resolution so he changed system font size so he can see text (not in my app). And that makes my big text size, HUGE and it doesn't shows well over LP image. It has nothing to do with accessibility. He will not decrease size just when he is using my app.

Comment: So, its not a jerkish move, just a (in this case) practical one. That is why I asked, if it can be done with single override, instead of using big `switch` or `if-else`, because either way, I'm making that text standard size for all font sizes >normal.

Comment: And anyway it still isn't something you should do. Because if you drop it globally, like you requested, it will effect every string in the app. Unless this is literally your only string, you will be harming the experience elsewhere